# System.outofmemoryexception while displaying data from datatable to datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private void newBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (txtDayfind.Text == "" || txtDatefind.Text == "" || 
            txtTimefind.Text == "" || txtLatfind.Text == "" || 
            txtLongfind.Text == "" || txtAddressfind.Text == "" || 
            txtaccuracy.Text == "" || txtTypefind.Text == "")
        {
            Button button = sender as Button;
            string content = button.Content.ToString();
            foreach (DataTable table in dsr.Tables)
            {
                if (table.TableName == content)
                {
                    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
                    dtselect = table;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = dtselect.DefaultView;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I am trying to display data from DataTable to Datagrid but DataTable contains more than 0.2 Million rows so it gives System.OutOfMemoryException. And I am not able to display data and application stop working.

Please help me to resolve `System.OutOfMemoryException` this issue. 
I have one dataset which contains multiple tables when DataTable has small data it works fine, but when DataTable have big data it consumes more space and give  System.outofmemoryexception.

Comment: Don't load all the data at once, only retrieve the data shown on screen and use paging too load the rest

Comment: use paging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.allowpaging?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: it is windows application and I am not done paging before can you help me with my code, please.

Comment: AFAIU you are in 32bit mode, you can try to switch to 64bit to allow your app using more memory, but anyways i agree with others that paging is needed here.

Comment: is their any another way instead of paging for doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Viewbox Grid.Row="3" Stretch="Fill">
                <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" Grid.Row="3" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" BorderThickness="0" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Height="600" Width="auto" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"   Background="#b5d2fc"  ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader" SelectionMode="Extended" CanUserDeleteRows="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Day"  Binding="{Binding Day}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Time" Binding="{Binding Time}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Lat" Binding="{Binding Lat}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Long" Binding="{Binding Long}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="400" Header="Address" Binding="{Binding Address}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Accuracy" Binding="{Binding Accuracy}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Type}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
                </Viewbox>
```

I simply add Viewbox and my code works fine if I load more than two files which have huge data then also it consume less memory

Answer (score 1):

If error fires when you read data from database, then pagination is your solution.

But if you get an error when WPF binds your collection to DataGrid and renders it, you can try set DataGrid `EnableRowVirtualization` property to true. If you do so, only rows, currently displayed on screen will be rendered.

**UPDATE:** I think, you don't quite understand, what paging is. Paging is loading data from the table in chunks (pages). Something like this (Note: I understand, that plain string non-parametrized queries are evil, but I'll use it for simplicity).

In your view-model class or in Code Behind you define two variables:

```
int pageSize;
```

and

```
int currentPage = 0;
```

and when you define a query string for loading data you don't just use

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM [your_table_name]";
```

but

```
string query = $"SELECT * FROM [your_table_name] OFFSET {pageSize*currentPage} ROWS FETCH NEXT {pageSize} ROWS ONLY";
```

When you execute this query it will return you not all records from the table, but `pageSize` rows, starting from `currentPage`

And in your interface you should put two buttons, which will increase or decrease `currentPage` and load next page. Or a possibility to move to a certain page manually by page number. It's up to your and your application design.

Comment: Paging I cant  do so I want to display data using a horizontal scrollbar.